# Reading environment variables from file with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I have a number of bash/shell variables in a file, I would like to read them into a node.js script (or javascript I guess) to eval them and set javascript variables.

e.g. the file contains:

gateway_ip=192.168.1.1

mask=255.255.255.0

port=8080

I've tried the following:

```
function readConfigFile() {
    var filename="/home/pi/.data-test";

    fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        for(var i = 0; i < lines.length-1; i++) {
         console.log(lines[i]);
         eval(lines[i]);
         console.log(gateway_ip);
         }

    });
}
```

and it spits out the lines as text, but I doesn't seem to be able to make the javascript variable. The error is:

undefined:1
default_gateway=192.168.1.1

Is there something obvious I've missed here?

Comment: you can write config in JSON file, and simply `require` as Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing here is `eval('gateway_ip=192.168.1.1')`.

`192.168.1.1` is not valid javascript. It should have quotation marks. Try this instead:

```
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    var options = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length-1; i++) {
      var parts = lines[i].split('=');
      options[parts[0].trim()] = parts.slice(1).join('=').trim();
    }
    // You now have everything in options.
```

You can use `global` instead of `options` to set those variables on the global scope.

Comment: good answer. 2 minor suggestions: 1. trim() the line and both sides. 2. replace `parts[1]` with `parts.slice(1).join("=")` to not throw away parts of a value with an `=` in it

Comment: Thanks, I will use this. (I was hoping there was a simple one-liner though).

Answer (score 1):

This is not very JavaScript-ish. An easier way to do it is to use JSON for your config file. For example, use this `config.json`:

```
{
    "gateway_ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "mask": "255.255.255.0",
    "port": "8080"
}
```

Then you can simply `require` it:

```
var config = require('./config.json');
console.log(config);
```

An additional bonus is that this will also catch formatting errors in the JSON file.

Comment: Thanks, yes I know, the reason it is done like this is because it is used to configure the network settings on a Raspberry Pi upon boot. The options are presented as defaults as last used.